# How to migrate from SVN to GIT Locally

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm working on a project that initially used Subversion, but the remote repository was removed and i don't want to use Subversion any more. I want to migrate it to git.

There's a way to do it without the remote repository, keeping all revisions history (without doing a `git init .`)?

I've already made a subversion to git migration with git-svn with no problems it on other projects, but they were on remote repository and i cannot find any info about migrating it locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion is not like Git, it does not keep the repository in your working folder, so you are going to be unable to migrate it.

You will need to create a new repository and check it in as if it was new code.

Answer (score 1):

> There's a way to do it without the
>   remote repository, keeping all
>   revisions history (without doing a git
>   init .)?

Short answer: no.

Unlike git, subversion is a *centralized* version control system, meaning it stores all revisions history *in the server*.

In contrast, *distributed* version control systems like git, [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), or [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) store all revisions history *locally*. In the latter case, you can indeed import/export between repositories with relative ease. In the former, you need the server's presence to do so.

Answer (score 0):

"svn switch --relocate" to the rescue [1].

Firstly you'd have to set up a temporary svn repository in any ordinary server and then relocate your 'local' svn repository (aka working copy) to that server, commit it to there, then use git-svn live you've done before.

---

[1] http://webkit.org/blog/97/svn-repository-location-change/

Comment: This doesn't retain all revisions as they were kept on the *original* server. This commit will only have latest one which. So git-svn will only download one revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can only keep the information from the subversion history if you manage to get your hands onto a proper backup of the remote subversion repository that was removed.

Otherwise, the history is lost, and you will just have to start from scratch.

If you do have a backup (such as an rsync copy of the SVN repo files on the server), you can locally do a conversion using `git svn` by pointing it to the local SVN repo copy via a `file://` URL, without doing a special SVN server setup first.